# Append First Line to the Following Lines until next blank line?

Tags: regex, replace

**I've got data in this form:**

```
Lastname, Firstname
[x] Title, (Dates, Abbreviations) Comment
[y] Something, (Dates, Abbreviations) Another Comment
Title, (Dates, Abbreviations)

Another Lastname, Firstname
[G] Big Deal, (Dates, Meaning) Comments
[y] Reptitions, (Dates, Abbreviations) Just Because
Awesome Title, (Dates, Something Else)
```

**I would like to turn that into:**

```
Lastname, Firstname, [x] Title, (Dates, Abbreviations) Comment
Lastname, Firstname, [y] Something, (Dates, Abbreviations) Another Comment
Lastname, Firstname, Title, (Dates, Abbreviations)

Another Lastname, Firstname, [G] Big Deal, (Dates, Meaning) Comments
Another Lastname, Firstname, [y] Reptitions, (Dates, Abbreviations) Just Because
Another Lastname, Firstname, Awesome Title, (Dates, Something Else)
```

**Remove the first line, append it to the following lines until the next blank line, and then start over.**

Still trying to crack RegEx :) It's magic voodoo to me.

Comment: You don't need regex for this, just simple string processing. What language are you looking for - Python, Javascript, Java, something else?

Comment: If you must use regex, maybe [this](https://regex101.com/r/dGNER3/1) is a starting point but there are cleaner ways for sure.

Comment: Python would be fine. Probably a better building block to understand it..
Hmm.. that looks pretty different than I imagined it would for RegEx..